# How to identify a "Socket closed" exception

Tags: java, android

I have a ServerSocket waiting to accept connections. Upon receiving a certain event on another thread, I close the socket so it no longer waits for connections. I receive a *java.net.SocketException* with "*Socket closed*" message. The problem is, how to identify the "Socket closed" exception. I can use the exception message to do this, but I feel it's not how I should handle exceptions.

I looked up the documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/SocketException.html

There are a number of subclasses to the SocketException class, but I couldn't find anything that refers to the "Socket closed" thing. Is it ok to use the exception message to identify it? Could this message ever change, maybe on another platform or something?

Here's some code:

```
try {
    // Wait for connection,
    connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();

} catch (SocketException e) {

    // How to identify the "Socket closed" exception?
    // ...

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is:

1. Define a 'stop' flag.
2. Set it when you want the server to stop accepting.
3. Set a shortish socket timeout on the server socket, say a few seconds.
4. When you get a connection or incur the timeout, check the flag, and proceed accordingly.